# What happened with linux sort -g?

Tags: linux, sorting

The file I want to sort is:

```
ABC
EUR
USD
Ba
ABC
B
B
C
CNY
g
USD
USDBFHE
V
YDHFKEFN
EUR
EURYSHK
```

Sorted:

```
a
ABC
B
B
C
CNY
g
USD
USDBFHE
V
YDHFKEFN
EUR
EURYSHK
```

Sort key is:

```
sort -t $'\t' -k 1,1g -f
```

Why are words starting with E always staying last?

Comment: I'm getting different output. What's your `locale` settings? Also, do you get something else when omitting the `g`?

Comment: @choroba I used gitbash to run this command and these words were in txt file. My env is windows 7.

Comment: I'm not able to duplicate your results. When I run that I get the words in alphabetical order as you would expect. I'm using gnu sort 5.3.0 from GNU coreutils, on Windows 10. I suspect a text encoding issue. Try copying the data from this page, paste to a file on your system, and then sort that file. I suspect that it'll work just fine. If it does, then there's a text encoding issue you need to address.

Comment: @JimMischel I found that when I sorted this file, words start with E considered as 0, so I got my result as above. Let me try to change text encoding.